# Rails HABTM Query based on count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

In my Rails app, Users have and belong to many Projects, and Projects have and belong to many Users.

I'd like to do a query for users who have more than one project, returning the activerecords for all users that meet this criteria.

How do I perform this query in the Rails console?

I thought I could do something like:

```
User.joins(:projects).where('projects.count > ?', 0)
```

But since count is not an attribute of projects, this doesn't work.

Comment: Use "having" and "group" to use conditions based on an aggregate function.  Alternately, you can do this query with a subquery: User.where("id in (select user_id from projects_users)")

Answer (score 2):

To use `having` you need to group first.

```
User.joins(:projects).group('projects_users.user_id').having('count(projects.id) > 1')
```

But better too, to change your HABTM association to be changed to a `has_many` - but there's plenty of extra benefits to having a join model between `users` and `projects` (like tracking *when* they were associated, *who* associated them, and stuff like whether they have any specific role in the project, etc) that the association change would be recommended anyway.

Comment: Have changed the typo in `group('projects.user_id')` to `group('projects_users.user_id')` so it now works for HABTM

Answer (score 0):

```
User.joins(:projects).group('projects_users.user_id').having('count(projects.id) > 1').count
```

It will return a hash with keys of project_ids and value of count if its greater than 1.